# SharePoint 2010 Lists: Multiple views on same page?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, list, list-view, content-approval

I am pretty new to SharePoint and using the 2010 version for my work.  I was tasked with creating a "to-do" List and a finalized List, both of which should preferably appear on the same screen.  Currently I have a regular List where items can be Approved/Rejected, and if they are approved, they appear in a second List View, which I named "Approved."

To access the "Approved" View, one has to click a link and go to another screen.  Is there a way for this View to appear on the first screen beneath the regular View, without having to go to a new page?

Thanks.

Comment: You can edit the page and add two app/list webparts pointing to same list but different views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to do this -

1. Create a blank webpart page.
2. Edit the page and add two webparts.
3. In the first webpart, add the list (the regular list view that you are referring)
4. In the second webpart, add the same list, but with the "Approved" view.

You can edit the view in the webpart by clicking the "Edit web part" from edit page.